# calculate exit rate in google datastudio

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, looker-studio

I'm trying to accomplish the following in either Google Analytics or Google datastudio:

I have a series of events which are allways triggered in identical order. The event category is the page that someone's on. Now I want to calculate the percentage of people that are left.

EA(event action)

EL(event label)

EA: A (100)

EA: B, EL: 1 (90, 90%)

EA: B, EL: 2 (80, 89%)

EA: B, EL: 3 (70, 87.5%)

EA: C (60, 86%)

If this isn't possible I would like to see it as a percentage of the total of step A which should be the same as pageviews. So then you'll get the following:

EA: A (100)

EA: B, EL: 1 (90, 90%)

EA: B, EL: 2 (80, 80%)

EA: B, EL: 3 (70, 70%)

EA: C (60, 60%)

I've searched a lot for something in datastudio or analytics that could get me on my way but I'm really lost here. There has to be someone out there that knows how to achieve this or tell me that I'm doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage of total is now supported in Data Studio using [Analytics Functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7512288#apply-analytical-functions).